# How do you see all files on Windows 7

Tags: windows, command-line, filesystems

I have several ghost and other unneeded files of the type C:\ xxx. I can see them when I click on "Computer". But when I try to remove them by using Command Prompt it automatically starts at `C:\USERS\DAN`, downstream from the ghosts.

Is there a way to see and remove files of the C:\ xxx type?

Comment: Why don't you just go backwards one directory using the command "cd .."

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply typing:

```
cd C:\
```

into the command prompt. Then, as an Administrator:

```
DEL /F <unneeded file(s)>
```

If, for any reason, the files aren't on the C: drive you will have to switch drives like this:

```
<drive letter>:
```

i.e

```
D:
```

Comment: You can also switch to a different drive letter by adding the `/D` switch. For example, from `C:` switch to `E:` with `CD /D E:\ `

Comment: I totally forgot about that. Haven't used the CMD for a long time, thanks for the reminder, @Twisty!

Answer (score 1):

From the Command Prompt, you switch to the "root" of the C: drive using the CD command as follows:

```
CD C:\
```

You can then view the files in the root directory with the command:

```
DIR
```

Finally, to delete files use the `DEL` command as follows:

```
DEL filename /F
```

Or to delete a folder use:

```
RD foldername
```

If the folder contains any subfolders, you must add the `/S` parameter:

```
RD foldername /S
```

You can view help for all of these commands by typing the command name followed by `/?`.  For example:

```
CD /?
```

Comment: Ninja'd me. Well put.